# Detecting collision with the sides of a GroupSingle and Group

Tags: python, pygame

When the frisk sprite is colliding with any sprite in npc_group, I want the former to move back the opposite direction of the side it's moving into, so that it doesn't move through it. I already have the collision detection down, but how do I detect the side of the sprites in npc_group being collided with to achieve this effect?

```
import pygame
from pygame import sprite
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.display.set_caption("UNDERRUNE")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed() #updates which keys are being pressed

class Frisk(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        friskd1 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_d1.png').convert_alpha(),(38,58))
        friskd2 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_d2.png').convert_alpha(),(38,58))
        friskd3 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_d3.png').convert_alpha(),(38,58))
        friskd4 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_d4.png').convert_alpha(),(38,58))
        self.frisk_d = [friskd1,friskd2,friskd3,friskd4]
        friskr1 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_r1.png').convert_alpha(),(34,58))
        friskr2 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_r2.png').convert_alpha(),(34,58))
        self.frisk_r = [friskr1,friskr2,friskr1,friskr2]
        frisku1 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_u1.png').convert_alpha(),(38,58))
        frisku2 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_u2.png').convert_alpha(),(38,58))
        frisku3 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_u3.png').convert_alpha(),(38,58))
        frisku4 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_u4.png').convert_alpha(),(38,58))
        self.frisk_u = [frisku1,frisku2,frisku3,frisku4]
        friskl1 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_l1.png').convert_alpha(),(34,58))
        friskl2 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_l2.png').convert_alpha(),(34,58))
        self.frisk_l = [friskl1,friskl2,friskl1,friskl2]

        self.walkframe = 0
        self.image = self.frisk_d[self.walkframe]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (320,240))
        #self.collisionbox = self.get_rect(bottom = (frisk.x,f))
        self.facing = 1

        self.vel = 3
        self.moving = False
        self.moving_x = False
        self.moving_y = False
        #self.movement = {moveup: False, movedown: False, moveleft: False, moveright:}

    def player_input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and self.rect.top > 0:
            self.rect.y -= self.vel
            self.facing = 0 
            self.moving_y = True
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and self.rect.bottom < 480:
            self.rect.y += self.vel
            self.facing = 1 
            self.moving_y = True
        else:
            self.moving_y = False
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.rect.x -= self.vel
            self.facing = 2
            self.moving_x = True
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and self.rect.right < 640:
            self.rect.x += self.vel
            self.facing = 3
            self.moving_x = True
        else: 
            self.moving_x = False
        # RUNNING
        if keys[pygame.K_LSHIFT]: self.vel = 10
        else: self.vel = 6

    def frisk_anim(self):
        if self.facing == 0:
            self.image = self.frisk_u[int(self.walkframe)]
        elif self.facing == 1:
            self.image = self.frisk_d[int(self.walkframe)]
        elif self.facing == 2:
            self.image = self.frisk_l[int(self.walkframe)]
        elif self.facing == 3:
            self.image = self.frisk_r[int(self.walkframe)]

        self.walkframe += 0.2
        if self.walkframe >= len(self.frisk_d): self.walkframe = 0
        if self.moving_x == False and self.moving_y == False: self.walkframe = 0
    
    def collision(self):
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,npc_group,False):
            self.rect.x += self.vel

    def update(self):
        self.player_input()
        self.frisk_anim()
        self.collision()

class NPC(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, type):
        super().__init__()

        if type == 'npc1':
            npc1_1 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/npc1_1.png').convert_alpha(),(38,58))
            npc1_2 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/npc1_2.png').convert_alpha(),(38,58))
            self.npc_image = [npc1_1,npc1_2]
            self.location = (100,100)
        if type == 'npc2':
            npc2 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('assets/npc1_2.png').convert_alpha(),(55,58))
            self.npc_image = [npc2]
            self.location = (250,50)

        self.image = self.npc_image[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = self.location)

# GROUPS
frisk = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle() # group contains sprite
frisk.add(Frisk())

npc_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
npc_group.add(NPC('npc1'))

# GAME LOOP
while True:
    # BACKGROUND
    #screen.blit(pygame.image.load('assets/bg.png').convert_alpha(),(0,0))
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    # QUIT
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    # FRISK
    frisk.draw(screen)
    frisk.update()

    npc_group.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update() # updates the display surface
    clock.tick(30) # tells pygame that this while True loop shouldn't run faster then 60 fps
```

Answer (score 0):

You know which direction you are moving, so you also know which side you hit an object on. The side of the collision depends on the relative movement of the 2 objects. The relative movement is the difference in movement between the player and the obstacle. If the obstacle stands still, it is the player's movement.

```py
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,npc_group,False):
    if self.facing == 0:
        self.rect.y += self.vel
    elif self.facing == 1:
        self.rect.y -= self.vel
    elif self.facing == 2:
        self.rect.y += self.vel
    elif self.facing == 3:
        self.rect.y -= self.vel
```

Alternatively, you can estimate the side by calculating the difference in object position and finding the side with the minimum distance. Note [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) return a list containing all intersecting sprites:

```py
hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, npc_group, False):
if hit:
    hit_rect = hit[0].rect

    dr = abs(self.rect.right - hit_rect.left)
    dl = abs(self.rect.left - hit_rect.right)
    db = abs(self.rect.bottom - hit_rect.top)
    dt = abs(self.rect.top - hit_rect.bottom)

    if min(dl, dr) < min(dt, db):
        if dl < dr:
            self.rect.x -= self.vel
        else:
            self.rect.x += self.vel
    else:
        if dt < db:
            if dl < dr:
                self.rect.y -= self.vel
            else:
                self.rect.y += self.vel
```